# Player Intercepting With Blocks On Teleport

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game on Unity which my player's main mechanic is teleporting wherever I click. I have achieved to make player only teleport when they are on ground, only withing a raidus and not into a block. But then I realized a problem which is if I click near a block it firstly intercepts with it then gets out. I understood that happens because my character gets teleported from center and because of that, if I click on a vertical wall it thinks I am on ground (because collider beneath player is triggered) and main idea of game just collapses.
I have tried to send rays to 4 sides but it got pretty messy and didn't work. I asked people how I do it and they said wherever you click use OverlapBoxNonAlloc and sent me a code but I didn't pretty understand how to use it in my codes.
I am putting here my whole code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public Vector2 groundChecker;
    public float castDistance;
    public LayerMask groundLayer;

    public Collider2D playerCollider;
    Vector2 playerTop;
    Vector2 playerBottom;
    private float playerHeight;
    private float distanceFromBlockBottom;

    void Update()
    {
        //If character is on ground and left mouse button is clicked, check how far the point you clicked from the player and teleport
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && IsGrounded())
        {
            //Calculating distance between mouse clicked point and player point
            Vector2 playerPosition = player.transform.position;
            Vector2 clickedPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            Vector2 distanceFromPlayer = clickedPosition - playerPosition;

            //Checking if mouse clicked point is a game object that can't be teleported
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, Mathf.Infinity);

            if (hit.collider == null)
            {
                if (distanceFromPlayer.magnitude < 3)
                {
                    player.transform.position = clickedPosition;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public void CalculateBlockDistance()
    {
        //Getting players center height
        playerCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        playerTop = playerCollider.bounds.max;
        playerBottom = playerCollider.bounds.min;
        playerHeight = playerTop.y - playerBottom.y;

        Vector2 clickedPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Vector2 playerPosition = player.transform.position;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(playerPosition, 3);
    }

    public bool IsGrounded()
    {
        if(Physics2D.BoxCast(transform.position, groundChecker, 0, -transform.up, castDistance, groundLayer))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

And here is a clip of my game and the problem: https://vimeo.com/845498509?share=copy
I am having trouble with this problem and I am pretty new in this unity stuff. So can you please explain me what, why and how should I do to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: If someone has sent you some code, why not use unitys documentation to understand what it does.  You havent included it, but id imagine it checks you have no walls or objects within its bounds.. so.. start there